# User dictionaries - trying to search for keys in dictionary and retrieve the multiple values associated with the key eg phone and email

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, key

Ive got a dictionary of keys that have multiple values. i then create a temporary list to hold the keys aka names of the person.
however i cant retrieve the values associated with them or am not sure how to save the key tuples into a list where i can iterate through and then print out the names with its associated values the user has searched for

```
contacts = { ("Andy", "Symons", 0): ["0151 231 2635", "", "", "a.symons@ljmu.ac.uk"],
                    ("Kirsty", "Lever", 0): ["0151 231 2350", "", "", "K.E.Lever@ljmu.ac.uk"]}

#########################
# Function Declarations #
#########################
def searchContacts(contacts):
    surname = input("Please enter the contacts surname: ")
    firstname = input("Please enter the contacts firstname: ")

    if len(contacts) == 0:
        print("no contacts found")#if the length of the dictionary equals = 0(checks if there is anything in the dictionary)
    else:
        templist = list(contacts.keys()) #creates a temporary list of the keys in the dictionary 
        print(tempdict)

    if (firstname, surname, 0) in templist: #searches through the temporary list to find the names
        print("Firstname : " + firstname , "Surname : " + surname) #formats names
    else: 
        print("error")#if cannot match name print error





################
# Main Section #
################


searchContacts(contacts)#calls function
```

output:
Please enter the contacts surname: Symons\n
Please enter the contacts firstname: Andy\n
[('Andy', 'Symons', 0), ('Kirsty', 'Lever', 0)]\n
Firstname : Andy Surname : Symons

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `dict.get` to obtain the value associated with a given key.

```py
result = contacts.get((firstname, surname, 0), "Not found")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `.get()` to get the values from the dict.

Like this:

```
values = contact.get(fistname, surname, 0)
```

Then iterate through the list to do the formatting you want.